# CSS animation translateZ and other jerky in Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Firefox v59.0.1 on Windows 10.

These examples work smooth in Chrome and Edge on Windows 10, but in Firefox v59.0.1 it is jerky.

**How can I make the animation smooth in Firefox?**

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/6amoyovo/16/) with transition.

```css
.stack {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.stack .stack-image,
.stack .stack-image-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.stack .stack-image-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stack .stack-image-content img,
.stack .stack-image-content svg {
  max-width: none;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-stack {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 200%;
}

.hover-stack .hover-stack-image-container {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.hover-stack .stack__deco {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.hover-stack.RigelFx .stack__deco {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition-property: transform;
  transform: translateY(0) translateZ(0);
}

.hover-stack.RigelFx .hover-stack-image-container {
  transition: transform 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transform: translateY(0) translateZ(0);
}

.hover-stack.RigelFx .hover-stack-image-container img,
.hover-stack.RigelFx .hover-stack-image-container svg {
  transition: transform 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transform: translateY(0) translateZ(0);
}

.hover-stack.RigelFx.hover-stack-run-animate .stack__deco:nth-child(1),
.hover-stack.RigelFx:hover .stack__deco:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(0) translateZ(0);
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.hover-stack.RigelFx.hover-stack-run-animate .stack__deco:nth-child(2),
.hover-stack.RigelFx:hover .stack__deco:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateZ(10px);
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.hover-stack.RigelFx.hover-stack-run-animate .stack__deco:nth-child(3),
.hover-stack.RigelFx:hover .stack__deco:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-20px) translateZ(20px);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hover-stack.RigelFx.hover-stack-run-animate .stack__deco:nth-child(4),
.hover-stack.RigelFx:hover .stack__deco:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateY(-30px) translateZ(30px);
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.hover-stack.RigelFx.hover-stack-run-animate .hover-stack-image-container,
.hover-stack.RigelFx:hover .hover-stack-image-container {
  transform: translateY(-40px) translateZ(40px);
}

.hover-stack.hover-stack-enable-scale.RigelFx.hover-stack-run-animate .hover-stack-image-container img,
.hover-stack.hover-stack-enable-scale.RigelFx:hover .hover-stack-image-container img,
.hover-stack.hover-stack-enable-scale.RigelFx.hover-stack-run-animate .hover-stack-image-container svg,
.hover-stack.hover-stack-enable-scale.RigelFx:hover .hover-stack-image-container svg {
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="stack" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="stack-image selectable hover-stack-enable-scale hover-stack RigelFx" il-type="settings" settings="data.icon" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" title="" alt="">
    <div class="stack__deco" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(61, 115, 133);"></div>
    <div class="stack__deco" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(61, 115, 133);"></div>
    <div class="stack__deco" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(61, 115, 133);"></div>
    <div class="stack__deco" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(61, 115, 133);"></div>
    <div class="stack-image-content hover-stack-image-container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 50%;"><img src="https://vemco.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image-banner2.jpg" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 285.714px; height: 285.714px; left: -42.8571px; top: -42.8571px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/vp3aogxv/1/) with animation.

```css
.stack {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.stack .stack-image,
.stack .stack-image-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.stack .stack-image-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stack .stack-image-content img,
.stack .stack-image-content svg {
  max-width: none;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-stack {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 200%;
}

.hover-stack .hover-stack-image-container {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.hover-stack .stack__deco {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.hover-stack.AltairFx {
  perspective-origin: 50% -50%;
}

.hover-stack.AltairFx .stack__deco {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes altair-image {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(0) rotateX(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateZ(18px) rotateX(-24deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(12px) rotateX(-16deg);
  }
}

@keyframes altair-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(0) rotateX(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateZ(6px) rotateX(-8deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(3px) rotateX(-4deg);
  }
}

@keyframes altair-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(0) rotateX(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateZ(9px) rotateX(-12deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(6px) rotateX(-8deg);
  }
}

@keyframes altair-4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(0) rotateX(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateZ(12px) rotateX(-16deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(9px) rotateX(-12deg);
  }
}

.hover-stack.AltairFx .hover-stack-image-container img,
.hover-stack.AltairFx .hover-stack-image-container svg {
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.hover-stack.AltairFx.hover-stack-run-animate .stack__deco:nth-child(1),
.hover-stack.AltairFx:hover .stack__deco:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition-delay: 120ms;
}

.hover-stack.AltairFx.hover-stack-run-animate .stack__deco:nth-child(2),
.hover-stack.AltairFx:hover .stack__deco:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.4;
  animation: altair-2 1400ms 90ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) forwards;
}

.hover-stack.AltairFx.hover-stack-run-animate .stack__deco:nth-child(3),
.hover-stack.AltairFx:hover .stack__deco:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.6;
  animation: altair-3 1400ms 60ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) forwards;
}

.hover-stack.AltairFx.hover-stack-run-animate .stack__deco:nth-child(4),
.hover-stack.AltairFx:hover .stack__deco:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.8;
  animation: altair-4 1400ms 30ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) forwards;
}

.hover-stack.AltairFx.hover-stack-run-animate .hover-stack-image-container,
.hover-stack.AltairFx:hover .hover-stack-image-container {
  animation: altair-image 1400ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) forwards;
}

.hover-stack.hover-stack-enable-scale.AltairFx.hover-stack-run-animate .hover-stack-image-container img,
.hover-stack.hover-stack-enable-scale.AltairFx:hover .hover-stack-image-container img,
.hover-stack.hover-stack-enable-scale.AltairFx.hover-stack-run-animate .hover-stack-image-container svg,
.hover-stack.hover-stack-enable-scale.AltairFx:hover .hover-stack-image-container svg {
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="stack" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="stack-image selectable hover-stack-enable-scale hover-stack AltairFx" il-type="settings" settings="data.icon" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" title="" alt="">
    <div class="stack__deco" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(61, 115, 133);"></div>
    <div class="stack__deco" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(61, 115, 133);"></div>
    <div class="stack__deco" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(61, 115, 133);"></div>
    <div class="stack__deco" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(61, 115, 133);"></div>
    <div class="stack-image-content hover-stack-image-container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 50%;"><img src="https://vemco.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image-banner2.jpg" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 285.714px; height: 285.714px; left: -42.8571px; top: -42.8571px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found this question [CSS animation jerky in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467987/css-animation-jerky-in-firefox) but answer don't help me.